# How do I setup CreatedAt and UpdatedAt in go-gorm join tables?

Tags: go-gorm

I am trying to setup audit timestamps for my GORM models.

How do I add UpdatedAt and CreatedAt timestamp fields for the many2many tables? For example, if I have a model like this, how do I set timestamps for customer_roles table?

```
type Customer struct {
    ID string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Email     string `gorm:"unique"`
    CreatedAt     time.Time
    UpdatedAt     time.Time


    Roles     []Role      `gorm:"many2many:customer_roles;"`
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't add extra field using gorm migration actually for many2many. You can split relation and add another entity customer_roles with one2many both side and do what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Eklavya good to know that. I already have the many to many table defined. If I change that I am wondering if that would get affected. I might just try that out.